# How to assign values inside lambda for python3?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, ubuntu-16.04

I am using python3.5 and Ubuntu 16.04 for my project.

There are 2 main things i am using in my python code. One is `map` and the other is `lambda`.
My code is:

```
tables=map(lambda(p,_) : {"geometry" : p, "properties" : {}},shapes)  (in python2)
```

The value/variable passed to lambda is a tuple of 2 parts. I am only interested in the 1st one and thus i am ignoring the 2nd one using underscore( _ ) but it is also assigned to `"properties"`.

The above code is in python2 and i am trying to replicate the same thing using python3. As of now i have changed few parts of the code to python3 like:

1. Braces after lambda gets removed `lambda(a,b) -> lambda a,b`
2. Unpacking of tuples in python3 lambda `lambda a_b : a_b[0] , a_b[1]`

Now my main question is **How to do the assignment operation inside lambda for python3?**`{"geometry" : p, "properties" : {}`

I have researched for quite sometime and have observed that most answers/questions are related to objects or python3.8, none of these i am using.

I don't know if there is any way to do this but if there is any please do share all the options.

Comment: what kind of data structure is `shapes`? Is it a list of tuples?

Comment: `shapes` consists of polygons. But i am less bothered about `shapes` because my main problem is to deal with the assignment inside `lambda` .